# How to get basePackages of @ComponentScan programatically at runtime?

Tags: spring-mvc, spring-boot

The scanBasePackages of `@SpringBootApplication` configured as follow:

```
package com.xxx.boot.sample;

@SpringBootApplication(scanBasePackages = { "com.xxx.boot.sample", "com.xxx.boot.service" })
public class DemoApplication {

  public static void main(String[] args) {
    SpringApplication.run(DemoApplication.class, args);
  }

}
```

The requirement is we want to integration [Apache Dubbo](https://github.com/apache/incubator-dubbo) component annotation scan with Spring Boot by programming at runtime for zero properties configuration, not by annotation.

```
@Configuration
@ConditionalOnClass({ EnableDubboConfig.class, AbstractConfig.class })
@ConditionalOnProperty(prefix = "dubbo", name = "enabled", havingValue = "true", matchIfMissing = true)
public class DubboAutoConfiguration {

  /// Dubbo配置

  @Configuration
  @EnableDubboConfig
  @ConditionalOnProperty(prefix = "dubbo.config", name = "enabled", havingValue = "true", matchIfMissing = true)
  @EnableConfigurationProperties(DubboProperties.class)
  public static class DubboConfigConfiguration {

  }

  /// Dubbo注解扫描

  @Configuration
  @ConditionalOnClass({ Service.class, Reference.class })
  @ConditionalOnProperty(prefix = "dubbo.annotation", name = "enabled", havingValue = "true", matchIfMissing = true)
  public static class DubboAnnotationConfiguration {

    @Bean(name = "serviceAnnotationBeanPostProcessor")
    @ConditionalOnMissingBean
    public ServiceAnnotationBeanPostProcessor serviceAnnotationBeanPostProcessor(BeanFactory beanFactory) {
      // 获取 Spring Boot 主入口类所在的包路径
      List<String> packagesToScan = AutoConfigurationPackages.get(beanFactory);
      if (packagesToScan == null) {
        packagesToScan = Collections.emptyList();
      }
      return new ServiceAnnotationBeanPostProcessor(packagesToScan);
    }

    @Bean(name = ReferenceAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.BEAN_NAME)
    @ConditionalOnMissingBean
    public ReferenceAnnotationBeanPostProcessor referenceAnnotationBeanPostProcessor() {
      return new ReferenceAnnotationBeanPostProcessor();
    }

  }

}
```

But `AutoConfigurationPackages#get(BeanFactory)` only return `"com.xxx.boot.sample"`, not include `"com.xxx.boot.service"`. I hope return all `scanBasePackages` value.

By debug, I found the `@SpringBootApplication` instance is a proxy class instance. I try to get Annotation use `Class#getAnnotations`, then get scanBasePackages field by reflection. But not success.

Question:

How to get `scanBasePackages of @SpringBootApplication` or `basePackages of @ComponentScan` programatically?

Answer (score 2):

It isn't really advisable to try to reuse the `scanBasePackages` attributes for your own purposes. If you look at the source of `@SpringBootApplication` you'll see the following:

```
@AliasFor(annotation = ComponentScan.class, attribute = "basePackages")
String[] scanBasePackages() default {};

@AliasFor(annotation = ComponentScan.class, attribute = "basePackageClasses")
Class<?>[] scanBasePackageClasses() default {};
```

This is saying that these attributes are an alias for `@ComponentScan`. Since this annotation can be used on any `@Configuration` class it's actually legal to have many of them.

The `@ComponentScan` annotation triggers scanning by the `ConfigurationClassParser`. Look at the `doProcessConfigurationClass` method for all the gory details.

If you really want to find the annotation attributes yourself you can do the following:

```
applicationContext.getBeansWithAnnotation(ComponentScan.class).forEach((name, instance) -> {
    Set<ComponentScan> scans = AnnotatedElementUtils.getMergedRepeatableAnnotations(instance.getClass(), ComponentScan.class);
    for (ComponentScan scan : scans) {
        System.out.println(Arrays.toString(scan.basePackageClasses()));
        System.out.println(Arrays.toString(scan.basePackages()));
    }
});
```

This will just get you those two values. You're still not considering any `@Condition` annotations or any include/exclude filters. You also won't deal with `@ComponentScan()` which means scan from the current package down.

What Spring Boot tends to do in these circumstances is define a new annotation for a specific purpose. For example, you can use `@EntityScan` to define where JPA entities are found. We then use `AutoConfigurationPackages` as the default value if you don't specify any override.

Comment: AnnotatedElementUtils.getMergedRepeatableAnnotations(instance.getClass(), ComponentScan.class, ComponentScans.class)